# Filter by sub document in mongdob not working

Tags: mongodb

Hello I am new in mongodb. I have products collection and each product have multiple variants and each variant having the multiple attributes. Now problem is that i am not able to filter with variant. Conditions

1. Search by product name -> Working
2. Search by Variant name -> not working  **filter by variants.variant_name Full Case**
3. Search by atttribute name -> working

[Mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/O_TGkDnTHWv)

Comment: what do you mean by not working search by variant means you only need to return that variant?

Comment: Yes i want to return that variant under product Full Case. "Test Case variant should not come." Check my mongo play ground

Comment: might want to use filter instead of map

Comment: can you share mongo play ground wih solution?

Comment: maybe like https://mongoplayground.net/p/rFRAKwv6RIJ

Comment: Thank you @cmgchess.. Post answer i will accept it.. dont have idea we can have multiple addFileds

Comment: @cmgchess is there any better query that i wrote for these all filters?

Comment: im not really sure as for now. i will post if i find shorter

Comment: I mean what i have acheive with  this mongo query.. is there any better way to write short query?

Comment: can combine the 2 addfields to 1 addfield if needed https://mongoplayground.net/p/6obIA9rVv_O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have a filter stage on the variants before handling the attributes inside the pipeline

```js
  {
    $addFields: {
      variants: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$variants",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$this.variant_name",
              "Full Case"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rFRAKwv6RIJ)